# Difference between support and set of points at which the density is positive

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, radon-nikodym

Consider a probability measure $P$ on the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ which is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\Lambda$, with density $dP/d\Lambda=p$.

Which is the difference between the support of $P$, say $\text{supp}(P)$ - defined as the smallest closed set $C \subset{\mathbb{R}^d}$ such that $P(C)=1$ - and the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: p(x)>0\}$?

Are the two sets equal? Or it might be that $ \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: p(x)>0\} \subset \text{supp}(P)$, with

$\Lambda(\text{supp}(P) \setminus \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: p(x)>0\})=0$,

i.e. the support and the set on which the density is positive differ by a Lebesgue-null set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say $A=\{x:p(x)>0\}$. The other answer is correct in stating that the support of $\mu$ is the closure $\overline A$. But $A$ need not be open, and $\overline A$ need not have the same Lebesgue measure as $A$.

Say $p=\chi_{[0,1]}$, the indicator function of the interval $[0,1]$. Then $A=[0,1]$, which is not open.

Enumerate the rationals as $\Bbb Q=\{r_1,r_2,\dots\}$. Let $I_n=[r_n,r_n+2^{-n}]$ and define $$p=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\chi_{I_n}.$$Then $A=\bigcup I_n$, so $\Lambda(A)<1$, while $\overline A=\Bbb R$, so $\Lambda\left(\overline A\right)=\infty$.

Comment: Do you have a proof that the support of $\mu$ is the closure $\overline{A}$? Can't $p$ take arbitrary values on Lebesgue sets of measure $0$, so in some sense $A$ can differ from the support of $\mu$ by a countable set? I came across this question while trying to show that $\Lambda \left ( \mathrm{supp} \mu \setminus \overline{A} \right ) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the word **closed**. You can define $supp(P)$ as the closure of the set $\{x \in  \mathbb{R}^d: p(x)>0\}$ but the latter is an open set. The two sets have the same Lebesgue measure so yes they differ by a Lebesgue null set.

Edit: I assumed in my solution that $p$ is a continuous function. If it is not, than $\{x \in  \mathbb{R}^d: p(x)>0\}$ need not be open. You might be able to come up with a sufficiently nasty $p$ so that the closure has bigger Lebesgue measure but I can't think of an example right now.

Comment: This was exactly my doubt, many thanks.

Comment: Do you have proofs in mind or are you just guessing? If the latter, please don't. If the former, your proofs are wrong: If $A=\{x:p(x)>0\}$ then $A$ need not be open, and $\overline A$ can have strictly larger Lebesgue measure than $A$.

Comment: @JackLondon You can'r believe everything you read on the internet. Math is sometimes an exception, _if_ there's a proof included...

Comment: Have you noticed that the current version doesn't actually assert anything? "P and Q. Except P is false, and I have no idea about Q".

Comment: Seriously. Given that,  as you state at the end, you really don't know whether or not the closure must have the same measure, why do you begin by asserting that it does?